# Does a compund layout always require its own class?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, custom-component

I want to define a compound layout in its most basic form, just a group of other views, with no  special methods, just grouping the views.

If I have a layout

```
<LinearLayout...>

    <LinearLayout...>
        <ImageView... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <TextView ... />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout...>
        <ImageView... />
        <TextView ... />
        <ImageView... />
        <TextView ... />
        <ImageView... />
        <TextView ... />
        <ImageView... />
        <TextView ... />
        <ImageView... />
        <TextView ... />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like just to have it like this

```
<LinearLayout...>

    <TopView>
    </TopView>

    <BottomView>
    </BottomView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So TopView and BottomView would be just two custom layouts grouping the above views.
Do I have to create a class for each of them custom layouts, even though I have nothing to extend over the grouping itself?
What would be the right syntax to name the files and to insert the custom layout into its XML parent.
Since layout files cannot have capital letter in their names, I would guess `topview.xml` and `bottomview.xml`, and **not** `top_view.xml` and `bottom_view.xml`
For the instantiation part in XML, it is not so clear to me how it would look like.

Every single example I came across in the web deals with more complex custom/compund layouts.

Note: The 2 samples of compound layout in *APIDemos* are not helpful, nor the *Android's Developer Guide* for [compund controls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

Comment: Why not use <include/> directive in order to deal with compounds?

Comment: @mr_archano I did not know the `<include />` element. It seems to work, at first glance. Would you care to post an aswer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should better use `<include/>` directive in your big layout, and define each sub-module in its own XML. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) to get an idea.